# Listing related entries based on category

Tags: stash, parse-order, gwcode-categories, related-entries

I want to list out related entries when viewing an entry, regardless of channel but according to the category of the entry.

On the page where the entry is output, I output the entry in a traditional {exp:channel:entries} tag and close it.

Then, I start a new tag where I thought I'd have to get the category_id first, before inserting that id into the channel:entries tag. I use Stash for that.

And my tags looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel1|channel2" limit='1' parse="inward"}
     {exp:stash:set name="cat" parse_tags="yes"}
        {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" last_only="yes" style="linear"}{cat_id}{/exp:gwcode_categories}
     {/exp:stash:set}

     <h1>{title}</h1>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And right before I want to output related entries, I can get the stash variable fine like this:

```
<h1>{exp:stash:get name="cat" process="end"}</h1>
```

But then, when I try to use this variable directly in the next tag, it comes out blank. Most likely because of parse order. I know the code works because if I manually add an ID for category, the entries as listed out like you'd expect.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel1|channel2" 
category='{exp:stash:get name="cat" process="end"}' limit="3" dynamic="no"}
      {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the correct parse order?
Edit: Yes, I can use an embedded template, which is what I'll be doing if I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just using the [`related_categories_mode=""` parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#related-categories-mode) on the channel:entries tag?